# using LoadSTL() function

Tags: battery, matlab

I what to convert .STL file to .mat to simulate object in m file in matlab. I am call the function like this way

**LoadSTL('F:\D Backup\najib\FYP\Dr istaz\matlab_sim_02\matlab_sim\quadfullprt.STL')**

but I get this error:

**File format in an unexpected type.
Check the file specified is an STL format file with ASCII formatting.

(Error - number of vertices not a multiple of 3)
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in LoadSTL (line 58)
    disp(numel(points.x))
Error in mainCoverter (line 3)
LoadSTL('F:\D Backup\najib\FYP\Dr istaz\matlab_sim_02\matlab_sim\quadfullprt.STL')**

how can I resolve this? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a robotics question.

Comment: Does not seem to be, however, anybody who tries to visualize robots in Matlab has a good chance of seeing this error message...

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the STL file in a viewing program like [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) (it's free and will open STL files), then save it as a new STL file but being sure to check ASCII format instead of binary. This might be a checkbox or it may be a separate file-type in the pull-down menu. For example, in MeshLab, after selecting STL and clicking "save", a new menu will pop up with extra options where you can de-select "Binary encoding".